# After creating SQL row, get data about that row within PHP bind_result method

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a function that inserts data into SQL table.

```
public function process_form(){
    # Start function when submit button is clicked
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
      # Assign form data
      $host = $_SESSION['logged_user'];
      $game = str_replace('g','',$_POST['game']);
      $region = str_replace('r','',$_POST['region']);
      $name = $_POST['match-name'];
      $mode = str_replace('mode_0','',$_POST['mode']);
      $bid = $_POST['bid'];
      # SQL query
      $q = '
        INSERT INTO matches(
          match_id,
          host,
          game,
          region,
          match_name,
          match_mode,
          started,
          start_time,
          finished,
          finish_time,
          validated,
          team_a,
          team_b,
          bid
        )
        VALUES (
          null,
          ?,
          ?,
          ?,
          ?,
          ?,
          0,
          null,
          0,
          null,
          0,
          null,
          null,
          ?
        );
      ';
      # Process SQL
      if ($stmt = $this->db->prepare($q)) {
        $stmt->bind_param('iiisii',$host,$game,$region,$name,$mode,$bid);
        $stmt->bind_result()
        $stmt->execute(VARIABLE_GOES_HERE);
        $stmt->close();
      }
    }
  }#endfunc(process_form)
```

And form that gathers needed data with action attribute which redirects user to next page where inserted data is displayed.

```
<form method="POST" action="match.php?id=VARIABLE_GOES_HERE">
```

I want to extend my SQL query within $q which will give me Id of currently created row and then within $stmt->bind_result() fill variable with the id. which will be then added within action attribute in form element.

Comment: Can you just get last insert id using `$lastId = $this->db->lastInsertId();` after the `execute`?

Comment: @Tristan  Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::lastInsertId() in D:\Programs\XAMPP\htdocs\PROJECT_ALPHA\create.php on line 133. Its maybe because I use mysqli instead of PDO. Would you suggest mysqli::$insert_id method instead?

Comment: Yes, that'll work. If you got the answer above, please post it here and accept your own answer. Don't keep the question open. Thanks.

Comment: Yes it is working and I posted answer, however I need to wait 2 days before I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What was needed is, to add this line of code: `$last_id = $stmt->insert_id;`

```
  if ($stmt = $this->db->prepare($q)) {
        $stmt->bind_param('iiisii',$host,$game,$region,$name,$mode,$bid);
        $stmt->execute();
        $last_id = $stmt->insert_id;
        $stmt->close();
```

and then within form this:

```
<form method="POST" action="match.php?id='.$last_id.'">
```